# ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex returns null after Insert

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a `ListBox` in a Windows Phone app. In a button action I need to set a transformation and name on every `ListBoxItem` in the `ListBox` called `lb`.

My datasource is

```
var items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    items.Add("Item " + i);
}
lb.ItemsSource = items;
```

I have a code to add a `RenderTransform` to each `ListBoxItem` in the ListBox

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count;++i )
{
    var item = this.lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem;
    item.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
    item.Name = i.ToString() //needed for storybord
    //another stuff
}
```

and it works ok. The problem is that I first need to insert and item to the list. When I call `items.Insert(index,"test")` before the for loop I get an exception that the item is null when `i==index`. It does not matter when I insert the new item, I always get null for that item.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there an event of the `ListBox` I need to wait for when I insert the new item before trying to acces the `ListBoxItem`?

**Edit**: I extracted the code and put it into a solution: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73642/PhoneApp2.zip. I first insert a fake item to the new solution, the fade it away and move the original item to that position using an animation.

Comment: `I have a code to add a RenderTransform to each ListBoxItem in the ListBox` You should do that in XAML. That's what XAML is for. Manipulating UI elements or their properties using procedural code in XAML-based technologies is very discouraged and introduces these kind of bugs, and also all kind of maintainability issues.

Comment: I do not think so. How to you set the Name or RenderTransform of a ListBoxItem in XAML when you have a binding?

Comment: What do you want the name for?? the `RenderTransform` can be applied using a `Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"`.

Comment: I have a StoryBoard referencing names of 2 items that should be switched using an animation. So I want to iterate the items, set these two names to those items and run the StoryBoard

Comment: Post your full code and XAML. Otherwise it's all speculations.

Comment: @HighCore Question updated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Waiting for the Dispatcher to finish doing what its doing such as (updating the UI because of a new item being added)

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   //Code Here
});
```

If you ever manipulate the UI such as adding an item to a listbox without the UI getting updated, you will not be able to run code targeting the UI.

Edit: Here is the code for your project to get working

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        start = Int32.Parse(from.Text);
        end = Int32.Parse(to.Text);

        fake = items[start];
        //items.Insert(end, fake);

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; ++i)
            {
                var item = this.lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem;
                item.Name = i.ToString();
            }


            (this.lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(end) as ListBoxItem).RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
            (this.lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(end) as ListBoxItem).Name = "listBoxItem1";


            (this.lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(start) as ListBoxItem).Name = "listBoxItem";

            sbListBox.Begin();
        });

    }
```

Comment: As far as I know, the code in code behind files is executed on the UI thread

Comment: yes but the UI hasn't updated with changes yet until after the code has ran and the dispatcher runs.

Comment: Wrap that code i posted around the for loop all the way down the the sbListBox.Begin() and watch the magic.

Answer (score 2):

Right after item added there is not container generated because of asynchronous nature of UI subsystem. Try subscribing on the ItemsChanged (or StatusChanged, sorry i don't remember) and get item when event is fired with proper event args.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. So, what event was the answer?